# How to add workflow tasks to a currently running workflow?

Tags: workflow, asp.net, tasks, exception-handling

I would like to know how I can add a new workflow task to a currently running workflow. Essentially, my scenario is this:

- created a custom application page approval form
- user can add new approvers via the form and press OK
- new approvers will be notified and assigned new workflow tasks, in addition to the original approver
- e.g. (approver 1 adds approver 2 and approver 3 .. originally approver 1 will only have the workflow task assigned to him, but after, approvers 2 and 3 will receive a notification regarding the task and they will also be able to access the workflow task).

I am trying to do this programatically but I encounter a "SPEXception" error, which upon research, is because the workflow is already currently running.

Is it possible to do this without restarting the workflow? I just want to add new workflow tasks for the new approvers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2010 if you click on the workflow status 'In progress' it takes you to the workflow history page.  There you will find 'Add or update assignees of .

You don't have to custome code this OOTB feature.

Carlene S.