# How to Add workflow task to currently running workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, flow, nintex

I have similar requirement of adding new user task after approval workflow started as mentioned in below question but in SharePoint Online that option is not available,

[How to add workflow tasks to a currently running workflow?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71032/how-to-add-workflow-tasks-to-a-currently-running-workflow)

E.g

- User uploaded document.
- Workflow tasks for 4 member of Approval groups created
- now i want to add task for new user so that workflow will proceed further only if 4+1 member approve the documents.

I tried with Nintex workflow and MS Flow but once workflow started there is no way to add new task for new user without stopping the workflow.

Can anyone suggest me whether it is possible in MS Flow or Nintex.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible, have you tried creating a 2010 workflow in designer to accomplish this?

Comment: I tried that but there is no such option available in sharepoint online.

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid it is not possible to add workflow tasks to a running instance, neither with SharePoint Designer workflow nor MS Flow.

Once a workflow/Flow instance has started, it cannot be modified.

You will have to start a new workflow/Flow instance to apply the changes on participants.